# Unable to connect to a repository while SVN-GIT fetch

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Can some one help me out on this issue,

When i try to run git svn fetch through the script on my windows

it says : **Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https:........' forbidden at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm**

While i get access to repo with the same id,pwd.

Comment: Check permissions. You're forbidden at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

That generally comes from [`perl/Git/SVN.pm`, line 310](https://github.com/git/git/blame/master/perl/Git/SVN.pm#L310)

Since your [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48829667/6309) suggests it was a BitBucket repository, you can follow the [official documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fishkb/403-forbidden-error-when-adding-a-new-repository-to-fisheye-or-when-indexing-282175110.html) (for Fisheye, but applicable to your case)

> - Check the account used to access the repository for group membership and read/write access.
> - Follow the instructions to implement one of the options detailed on the [**SVN Authentication Issues page**](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/svn-authentication-issues-960155841.html).
>     The recommended option is to "Specify the username as part of the URL when defining your repository location".