# Need history of already migrated SVN-GIT

Tags: bitbucket, tortoisesvn, git-svn, svn2git

I've migrated my SVN-GIT manually by just copying the folders to another git folder and pushing them to bitbucket. now i need the history of trunk from svn. can i get that now ?

If possible can i delete present trunk and move it back again. we are worried only about the trunk. There are no commits in trunk on bitbucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a proper SVN to git migration (best with the KDE `svn2git` tool, not with any other like nirvdrum `svn2git` or `git-svn`, for reasoning see e. g. my answer at [What dependencies does running "git svn" need to have installed in order to run correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712773/what-dependencies-does-running-git-svn-need-to-have-installed-in-order-to-run)), then force-push to BitBucket, that will replace what is currently in BitBucket.

Anyone that had this cloned and maybe made local branches based on it has to manually rebase of course like always with "Recovering from upstream rebase".